# How to load assets in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails; and I implement a new rails app with front view and admin view. I need to load assets based on the selected view means when I view admin section it only loads admin required assets.

By default rails build a application.js, I created a `admin.js` and place the code like in `application.js` and also add my custom assets which are placed in vendor folder but it not loaded any assets

This the code what actually I have

```
 #application.js
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //= require turbolinks
 //= require morris/morris (custom file placed in vendor folder)
 //= require_tree .

 #admin.js
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //= require turbolinks
 //= require morris/morris (custom file placed in vendor folder)
 //= require_tree .
```

The main problem is the custom file is loaded only when loads the application.js file

Answer (score 0):

Sprockets needs to know which files to compile. Add this to `config/application.rb`:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['admin.js']
```